# What is preventing my window managers from recognizing some key combinations?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard, window-manager

Since rebooting my system this morning, every window manager seems to have lost its capacity to recognize combinations of keys. I'd started noticing it in xfce4 when I tried to launch the quicklauncher by using <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>F2</kbd>. It didn't open, but my keystroke *did* insert `;3Q` in a terminal window that was active. How strange!

I started in investigating and no window manager keyboard shortcut that began with <kbd>Alt</kbd> worked. These were the results of trying them whilst in a terminal:

- <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>F1</kbd> resulted in `;3P`
- <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>F2</kbd> resulted in `;3Q`
- <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>F3</kbd> resulted in `;3R`
- <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>F4</kbd> resulted in `;3S`
- <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>F5</kbd> through <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>F12</kbd> resulted in `;3~`
- <kbd>∧</kbd> resulted in `A`
- <kbd>∨</kbd> resulted in `B`
- <kbd>></kbd> resulted in `C`
- <kbd><</kbd> resulted in `D`

This happens in every window manager that I have installed on my Debian system (xfce4, herbstluftwm, i3), so I suspect it probably has something to do with some global keyboard setting. Other key combinations do work, though.  I tried searching for solutions to the same problem, but all I could find was a question on Ask Ubuntu ([link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/190008/terminal-insert-a-b-c-d-on-shiftarrows-solution)), but the problem (and solution) of that question is really just about finding a way to copy-paste without this weird thing happening.

I also tried playing around with `XKBOPTIONS` and `XKBVARIANT` in `/etc/default/keyboard`, but that didn't seem change anything. Nor did plugging in an external USB keyboard or selecting a different key map in the keyboard settings.

[Gilles](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/277613/what-is-preventing-my-window-managers-from-recognizing-some-key-combinations?noredirect=1#comment482609_277613) suggested I'd try `xev`. This is the output of pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>F2</kbd>:

```
KeyPress event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x3a00001,
    root 0xc6, subw 0x0, time 1118145, (543,224), root:(2914,1086),
    state 0x0, keycode 64 (keysym 0xffe9, Alt_L), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XmbLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyPress event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x3a00001,
    root 0xc6, subw 0x0, time 1118305, (543,224), root:(2914,1086),
    state 0x8, keycode 68 (keysym 0xffbf, F2), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XmbLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False
```

What is preventing my window managers to recognize these key combinations?

Comment: Run `xev` from a terminal. When you press a key in `xev`, you'll see lines like `KeyPress event, serial …` Copy the whole paragraph (the most useful line is the `state …` one) for a press of `Up` and of `F1` with `Alt` down. Did you upgrade anything or change anything in your configuration recently (since the previous reboot)? Does pressing CapsLock, NumLock or ScrollLock make any difference?

Comment: I've copied the output to into my question (Although with `Alt`+`F2`). Pressing the lock keys like you suggested didn't appear to do anything.

Comment: The terminal is receiving the right keys — you're seeing the escape sequences (minus the initial escape-bracket) sent by the keychords. And the output of `xev`, confirms the keyboard is sending exactly what it should (and in particular no spurious modifiers). So this doesn't seem to be a problem on the keyboard configuration side, but on the window manager side, even if it affects several window managers.

Comment: Can you purge & re-install one of the window-managers ? Just to see if it is related to the window-manager configuration.

Comment: Apparently modifiers don't work as expected. If you still have the problem please edit your question to include the output of `xmodmap -pm`.